# Apply Angularjs directive in all elements buttons automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is possible apply directive in all elements buttons when page load automatically.

Comment: I would create my own directive my-button and use it instead of button tags.

Comment: I have a big application, is not possible edit all views now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just create a `button` directive.

```
angular.module("foo")
  .directive("button", function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, el) {
        // Do something with el
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but not work.
angular.module("foo")
  .directive("button", function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, el) {
       el.on('click',function(){
               alert('test');
        });
      }
    }
  });